# Google chrome extension help, I just need to run one line of javascript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to make a quick extension that runs a line of javascript whenever it is on a certain url, but I am have trouble figuring out how to do this. It isn't working, but I am not sure what is wrong and don't know how to troubleshoot this. Either a permission I am unaware of isn't set, the javascript is never executed or the javascript is just wrong! Thanks in advance for the help with this sort of naive question.

manifest:

```
{
"name": "name goes here",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "checks a box",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "https://urlofpage.com" ],
    "js": ["script.js"]
  }
]
}
```

here is the script

```
<script type = "javascript">
//<!--
var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkboxid");
checkbox.checked =true;

//-->

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have the HTML script tags in a .js file.

Comment: And that was it. Thank you. It was so obvious I completely missed it.